# How can I create multiple code like this one

Tags: javascript, html

How can I create multiple code like this one.

I want to have 2 or 3 same code, like : Video 1, Video 2, Video 3 Embedded video with same code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("p iframe").hide();
function toggle(obj) {
          var obj=document.getElementById(obj);

          if (obj.style.display == "block") obj.style.display = "none";
          else obj.style.display = "block";
}


</script>

<a href="javascript:%20void(0);" onclick="toggle('q1')">Video 1 Youtube</a>

<br />
<div id="q1" style="display: none;">
<iframe allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/b8B1O0Fak5s" width="420"></iframe></div>
```

Comment: You cannot have repeated ids in the same page, so try to add some code to generate these ids.
then, just check if function `toggle` is already defined: `if (toggle) function toggle(obj) {...`

Comment: I'm actually not understanding at all what you want to do.

Comment: I want to create a video embedded with different host. Like Video 1 Youtube, Video 2 Vimeo, Video 3 Dailymotion. with Hide and Show. But the other problem is im not really good in programming i only know basic HTML. can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your toggle function takes the name of the div the video is held in. So all you need to do is duplicate the link, div and iFrame.

This is common for all your videos

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("p iframe").hide();
function toggle(obj) {
          var obj=document.getElementById(obj);

          if (obj.style.display == "block") obj.style.display = "none";
          else obj.style.display = "block";
}


</script>
```

This is the link to show each video so will need to be duplicated each time

```
<a href="javascript:%20void(0);" onclick="toggle('q1')">Video 1 Youtube</a>
```

This is the display for your video and so will need duplicated too

```
<div id="q1" style="display: none;">
  <iframe allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/b8B1O0Fak5s" width="420"></iframe>
</div>
```

So to add a second and third video all you would do is follow your pattern. Notice how all the IDs are now "q2"

```
<a href="javascript:%20void(0);" onclick="toggle('q2')">Video 2 Youtube</a>
<div id="q2" style="display: none;">
  <iframe allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/SomeOtherVideo" width="420"></iframe>
</div>
```

The more complex solution is have one div/iframe which you pass the name of the video. This is by car the cleaner solution however I get the impression you're after a simple solution?

Comment: @user3480984 glad I could help. Please upvote the answers which helped you and mark the most appropriate one as accepted

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want something like this?

(Assuming jQuery)

```
<script type="javascript/text">
    if (typeof (toggle_visibility) != "function") {
        $(".toggle-container iframe").hide();
        var toggle_visibility = function () {
            $(this).parents(".toggle-container").find("iframe").toggle();
        }
        $(document).on("click", ".toggle-container .toggle-trigger", toggle_visibility);
    }
</script>
<div class="toggle-container">
    <a href="javascript:void();" class="toggle-trigger">Video 1 Youtube</a>
    <br />
    <iframe allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/b8B1O0Fak5s" width="420"></iframe>
</div>
```

A sample of 3 snippets in a row:
http://fiddle.jshell.net/qTk7F/1/

I added classes with selector purposes, and removed the unneded ids.